# Can't start Apache2, could not open error log file

Tags: apache2

Ok, so I have a related question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095675/cannot-start-restart-apache2-ubuntu-server), but I feel like this is a separate issue.

Every time I try to run

```
apache2 -k start
```

I get the error

```
(2)No such file or directory: apache2: could not open error log file /etc/apache2/${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log.
```

So after extensive research and browsing through configuration files, I am fairly certain that the path shown in the error message above should simply be

```
${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

which is the exact path in my `<VirtualHost>` file for error logging. Something is prepending `/etc/apache2/` onto the error log path, resulting in a final path of `/etc/apache2//var/apache2/log/error.log`, and I cannot for the life of me find out why that is.

I don't care what I need to do, whether it's disabling logging, finding the source of the prepended path, or reinstalling apache2, as long as I don't have to reinstall my entire OS. I have been at this for hours, and I'd really like an answer.

Comment: Edit your virtual host configuration (or /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default if you are using the default vhost) and change the value for ErrorLog to be /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0):

See if starting apache with the following command helps--

```
service apache2 start
```